# How to display numerals in context in Open Office Writer?

Tags: openoffice-writer

I just switched to Open Office Writer to complete a Word file which had been written using MS Word. There, I used to set numbers to show up in context, so that I could see Arabic numbers next to English text and Persian numbers next to Persian text. But, I see all numbers in Arabic in Open Office Writer. Is there an option I can set it to automatically match the context in which the number is used?

Note: Persian is right to left like Arabic. Persian digits are shown below:
[image: source:deus-ex-militaria.com]
(Image credit: deus-ex-militaria.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Languages`.  Check `Show UI elements for Bi-Directional writing`.  Then under `Default languages for document`, specify the CTL language as Persian.  Click OK.

Now go to `Tools -> Options` again.  Under `Language Settings`, it should now be possible to select `Complex Text Layout`.  Select `Context` in the drop-down list.

[image]

With those settings, entering numbered right-to-left text will use CTL numerals.

Note: In LibreOffice, the Languages menu looks a little different.  In that menu, instead of `Show UI elements for Bi-Directional writing`, the relevant check box is labeled `Complex Text Layout (CTL)`.

Comment: Thank you. That's it. Do you also know [how OO Writer can be made to automatically change keyboard to match surrounding text](http://superuser.com/questions/1034207/how-to-tell-open-office-writer-to-change-keyboard-language-to-match-surrounding)?