# How to set OpenOffice Writer to change keyboard language to match surrounding text?

Tags: openoffice-writer

In Microsoft Office options, there is a checkbox that when selected, changes keyboard language to match surrounding text, so it is very handy for those who switch between two languages frequently when typing complex words in their text. Actually, having enabled this, one does not have to manually switch keyboard via Shift+Alt (common keyboard combination for language switching on Windows). I recently switched to Open Office from MS Office. I need to know if there is such an option available in Open Office Writer? For example, I want the keyboard to automatically change to Persian if the cursor is in the middle of a Persian text line and the keyboard is English and I hit the End key on keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Apache OpenOffice nor LibreOffice has the capability to switch keyboard layouts automatically.  As you mentioned, use a shortcut such as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> instead.